# Why is Intl.NumberFormat inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, node.js

running `Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN',{ style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(5000)` returns US$5,000.00 on one machine but just $5,000.00 on another machine. Why is that so?

Comment: Is it the machine or a different browser?

Comment: Is `en-IN` a supported locale in both machines?

Comment: I am running it in node instead of browser.
how do I check if en-IN is supported in both machines?

Comment: Are they running the same node version?

Comment: no, will try changing version, but it doesn't make a lot of sense if the entire result of a function changes when the node version is upgraded

Comment: @Samson Why does it not make sense? See [`supportedLocalesOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/supportedLocalesOf). The runtime has to support a locale in order to format it properly. It is reasonable to expect that a given Node version doesn’t support every single locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it was due to different node versions, but it doesn't make a lot of sense to me that upgrading node versions actually changes the output of a string formatting library, when the point of string formatting functions should be to expect consistent output.